# Two-way data binding with calculations in Vue.JS?

Tags: vue.js

In Vue.JS I have two input boxes where you can enter values.

I want to change the value in the other box as I type in the first, and vice versa. But also do a computation at the same time.

I have tried using two watchers but it seems to break.

Example:

```
<template>
  <input v-model="box1">
  <input v-model="box2">
</template>

<script>
watch: {
  box1: function (val) {
    this.box2 = val + 100
  },
  box2: function (val) {
    this.box1 = val - 100
  }
},
</script>
```

This breaks when you adjust the values in the second box.

Is this possible to do in Vue?

Comment: It might work if you use `v-model.number`, but I still think [ittus' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353263/734040) is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is using methods instead of `watch`:

```
<template>
  <input :value="box1" @input="onBox1Input">
  <input :value="box2" @input="onBox2Input">
</template>

<script>
methods: {
  onBox1Input(value) {
    this.box1 = value
    this.box2 = value + 100
  },
  onBox2Input(value) {
    this.box2 = value
    this.box1 = value - 100
  }
}
</script>
```